# Cast (or rather: ascribe) collection type without specifying type parameter

Tags: scala, collections, type-parameter

Say I have a `List` of `Int`s

```
scala> val list = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
list: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Of course, Scala is smart enough to return the correct type for me. Now, considering, I’m not interested in the specific features of `List` but rather want to have a more general (super-) type, say, `Traversable`. Obviously, I can specify it:

```
scala> val trav = list: Traversable[Int]
trav: Traversable[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

but this means that I also have to repeat the type parameter.

This won’t work

```
scala> list : Traversable
<console>:9: error: type Traversable takes type parameters
       list : Traversable
              ^
```

And these two examples delete the type parameter information altogether

```
scala> list : Traversable[T forSome {type T}]
res2: Traversable[T forSome { type T }] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> list : Traversable[_]
res3: Traversable[Any] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Is there a way to get a `Traversable[Int]` without having to type `Int`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are asking for is basically a polymorphic function; or a function over higher-kinded types. You might define such a mapping between types * -> * as follows:

```
scala> trait ~>[F[_], G[_]] { def map[A](f: F[A]): G[A] }
defined trait $tilde$greater
```

You'd need an implicit instance of course

```
scala> implicit object ListIsTrav extends (List ~> Traversable) { 
  | def map[A](l: List[A]): Traversable[A] = l 
  | }
defined module ListIsTrav
```

Now add a converter for types of the form * -> *

```
scala> class Homomorphic[F[_], A](f: F[A]){  
  | def as[G[_]](implicit ev: F ~> G): G[A] = ev map f 
  | }
defined class Homomorphic

scala>  implicit def Type_Is_Homomorphic[F[_], A](f: F[A]) = new Homomorphic(f)
Type_Is_Homomorphic: [F[_], A](f: F[A])Homomorphic[F,A]
```

And now use it:

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3).as[Traversable]
res0: Traversable[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

The pain here is the exponential explosion of implicit instances of the `List ~> Traversable` sort. It's not that usable in practice.

Comment: Very insightful. Actually, I was originally only interested in the case `F[A] <:< G[A]` so there is no explosion of implicits.

Answer (score 2):

This works but is a lot of work to avoid typing Int... Maybe someone can come up with a more concise trick based on this.

```
scala> def traversableId[T](t: Traversable[T])= t
traversableId: [T](t: Traversable[T])Traversable[T]

scala> traversableId(list)
res1: Traversable[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

While [oxbow_lakes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16853/oxbow-lakes) gave a [great solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8945803/200266) on how to solve this problem for arbitrary combinations, he inspired me on how to do this for the case where `Traversable` is a super type of `List`. (This wasn’t originally specified in the question, though.)

```
class CastToSuperType[F[_], A](f: F[A]) {
  def as[G[_]](implicit ev: F[A] <:< G[A]): G[A] = f: G[A]
}

implicit def implCastToSuperType[F[_], A](f: F[A]) = new CastToSuperType(f)

scala> List(1, 2, 3).as[Traversable]
res0: Traversable[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

I suspect, types with an arbitrary number of type parameters might need type lambdas, though.

Comment: You'd need type lambdas if you wanted to view, say, a `Map[String, List[Int]]` as a `Map[String, Traversable[Int]]`

Answer (score 0):

Write a corresponding method:

```
def asTraversable[T](x: Traversable[T]) = x

asTraversable(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Collection classes have conversion methods for most of the generalized traits

```
scala> List(1,2,3).toTraversable
res0: Traversable[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> List(1,2,3).toIterable
res1: Iterable[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> List(1,2,3).toIndexedSeq
res2: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: I know. The question is more about what’s possible in general and from a syntactical point of view.

Answer (score 0):

In scala 2.10 it's much simpler, since the introduction of `.to[Col[_]]`, which is part of scala.collection.TraversableLike

here's the definition:

```
def to[Col[_]](implicit cbf : scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[scala.Nothing, A, Col[A]]) : Col[A]
```

So you can basically do:

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).to[Vector]
res0: Vector[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)


scala> List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).to[Set]
res1: Set[Int] = Set(5, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```